# How to replace url part before #

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ngroute

My angularJs App URL is opened via another application. URL to open my app looks like,

http://localhost:21770/App/IAnalytics?FromApp=abc#/PBIDefault

where FromApp is the parameter which indicates the source app from where angularjs app is called.

I would like to remove the FromApp=abc part from URL once my home page controller starts running.

I need to make sure by URL looks like,
http://localhost:21770/App/IAnalytics?#/PBIDefault

How can I achieve the same using $routeProvider or $location ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You look for `params` once your `home page controller` starts .
2. If you find a parameter, you change the state of your app to the home page of the app (But without parameters this time). you can use `$routeProvider`, `$location` or `$stateProvider` for that.

Like this:

```
if ($location.search().FromApp){
$state.go('app.home',null, { reload: true }); // 'app.home' is name of your home page state.
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the $location.search() & it is coming up with blank value.

Comment: This might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters